# Browser HTML source incomplete, even when full source verified as served

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, browser, loading

I'm experiencing the strangest problem. I have a development site page that for some users is rendering incomplete in all browsers. Viewing the source shows it to be cut off at a certain point, with no closing body or html tags anywhere. Logging the response body on the server when this page is being served to them, however, shows it to be complete. At first I thought it may be a network issue, but this problem has been experienced in multiple locations located far from either other. Just as strange, if the user loads the same complete source code as a static page instead of a dynamic one, the page renders correctly every time. I'm using Rails 2.3.8 w/ Rack 1.1.3, Passenger 3.0.9, and Nginx 1.0.6 FYI. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Check the Net tab in the browser's dev tools. Does the browser receive the full HTML code?

Comment: It doesn't, and viewing source shows the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. There was a large JSON object assigned to a variable on the page that was used to by the autocomplete methods of various fields. After removing this on-page JSON object and loading it from another URL using the jQuery getJSON() method, the problem went away. Definitely a rare issue, but hopefully this will help someone else.

Comment: That doesn't explain what caused the issue.  A slow load is one thing, truncation is another matter.

Comment: It may not explain it, but sometimes there isn't enough time to determine ultimate causes, just solutions that work.